# Catalog url rewrite stuck on REINDEX REQUIRED

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, reindex, catalog-url-rewrite

I am re-indexing Catalog url rewrite via cron, but it is always showing reindex required.

When I manually ran it via browser after deleting the locks file it works fine.

I ran reindex via command line and checked in admin, it is showing processing and after sometimes in command line it is showing re-index successful but in admin it is still showing reindex required and update date is also of day when I manually ran it.

Re-index mode is manual.

After deleting the var/locks manually everything just works fine.

Have anybody face this issue earlier?
What is the issue here?
How this can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried setting mode to manual. Then reindex from cli. Just curious if there may be some process that keeps invalidating the index.

Comment: @ProxiBlue Re-index mode is already set to manual. Update this in question as well.